# Can ConTeXt compile source to any other file format besides PDF?

Tags: context, export

If I run `context file.txt`, ConTeXt will create a PDF file. Can ConTeXt create any other types of output, such as HTML, EPUB (.epub) or Broad Band eBook (.lrf/.lrx)?

Comment: Have you seen the [XML](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/XML) page in the ConTeXt Garden?

Comment: Yes, ConTeXt can export to `xhtml`, `xml`, and `ePub`. For `xhtml` and `xml`, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267896/323). For `ePub`, see [context wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub).

Comment: @Aditya Would you like to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>[Aditya's comment as an answer]</sup>

Yes, ConTeXt can export to `xhtml`, `xml`, and `ePub`. For `xhtml` and `xml`, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267896/323). For `ePub`, see [context wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/epub).